# Current Calendar Enum EventColor

Tags: google-apps-script

Does anyone know the current numbers for Calendar EventColors
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-color Seems deprecated.

My calendar shows 12 colors to choose from.[image: Color Swatch]

Comment: Have you tried printing their values into Logger/Stackdriver? Or making the 12 needed events via the Calendar UI, and then fetching them and printing their colors via Apps Script?

Answer (score 3):

```
var color = 1;//Lavender
var color = 2;//Sage
var color = 3;//Grape
var color = 4;//Flamingo
var color = 5;//Banana
var color = 6;//Tangerine
var color = 7;//Peacock
var color = 8;//Graphite
var color = 9;//Blueberry
var color = 10;//Basil
var color = 11;//Tomato
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake the 12th represents the default Calendar color ("0"). Looks like they are all there. They are just slightly different in shade and Labelled differently.